# How so I use variables in an execSQL()?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to take some values stored from EditText fields and store them into my SQLLite DB.

I have the following String variables:

site_name
_address
_user
_pass

Here is the Sql command I'm trying to use:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("SiteManager", MODE_PRIVATE,
                null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SiteTable (Name VARCHAR, Address VARCHAR, Usernname VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR, PORT INT(4), Passive BIT);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO SiteTable VALUES ('" + site_name + "','"
                + _address + "','" + _user + "','" + _pass + "'," + _port + ","
                + _passive + ");");
```

I'm checking the value like this in another Activity:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("SiteManager",
                        MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SiteTable", null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                db.close();
```

In the debugger it's showing c as not having any values but the column names are there. So this makes me think there's something wrong with the way I'm trying to use variables in my SQL statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These have been sanitized, I hope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the standard Android binding, whose Javadoc is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html), then you can find the right code to call by looking at the Javadoc for an overload of `execSQL`. See [`SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(String, Object[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

Now, the Javadoc says that `execSQL` is not to be used for `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`. Instead, there are three `insertXXX` methods, each of which takes additional data in a `ContentValues` object.  So, you construct that object, which looks like a `Map`, with the new row's data.

Comment: I do not know how to fix the formatting on the second hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you are searching

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("insert into userTable (username,name,password,email) 
values('"+username+"','"+name+"','"+password+"','"+email+"') ");
```